# AppInvites "Install" link doesn't open the app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

It happens from time to time, also with Google's sample app (https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites). App is installed on device but instead of opening the app, "Install" link:

- Opens web browser on Lollipop and earlier, than it suggests to "Open with play store"
- Stucks on email client (Gmail) on Marshmallow. It seems that something is happening (status bar is blinking) but no app is opened.

Those are logs from Marshamallow (seems that Google apis returns some 401's):

```
09-10 08:14:12.692      795-813/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed 

com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity: +92ms
09-10 08:14:12.714  23045-23082/? E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa96e4530
09-10 08:14:12.752      795-804/? I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 599(43KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 35MB/51MB, paused 2.199ms total 171.864ms
09-10 08:14:12.875  23045-23093/? E/Volley﹕ [20360] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/plusdatamixer/v1/mutateonekey?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyAP-gfH3qvi6vgHZbSYwQ_XHqV_mXHhzIk
09-10 08:14:12.876  23045-23110/? E/AppInviteAgent﹕ Error communicating with server com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
09-10 08:14:12.896     795-1943/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://plus.google.com/... flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity} from uid 10011 on display 0
09-10 08:14:12.978  23045-23112/? W/BaseAppContext﹕ Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
09-10 08:14:13.024    1731-1731/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator﹕ onFinishInput()
09-10 08:14:13.047      795-813/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity: +88ms
09-10 08:14:13.070  23045-23082/? E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa96e4580
09-10 08:14:13.108      795-804/? I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 676(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 35MB/51MB, paused 2.421ms total 188.050ms
09-10 08:14:13.174  23045-23091/? E/Volley﹕ [20358] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/plusdatamixer/v1/mutateonekey?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyAP-gfH3qvi6vgHZbSYwQ_XHqV_mXHhzIk
09-10 08:14:13.175  23045-23112/? E/AppInviteAgent﹕ Error communicating with server com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
09-10 08:14:13.184     795-3345/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://plus.google.com/... flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity} from uid 10011 on display 0
09-10 08:14:13.266  23045-23081/? W/BaseAppContext﹕ Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
09-10 08:14:13.307    1731-1731/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator﹕ onFinishInput()
09-10 08:14:13.318      795-813/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity: +86ms
09-10 08:14:13.343  23045-23082/? E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa96e4530
09-10 08:14:13.387      795-804/? I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 604(43KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 35MB/51MB, paused 3.115ms total 181.567ms
09-10 08:14:13.480  23045-23092/? E/Volley﹕ [20359] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/plusdatamixer/v1/mutateonekey?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyAP-gfH3qvi6vgHZbSYwQ_XHqV_mXHhzIk
09-10 08:14:13.481  23045-23081/? E/AppInviteAgent﹕ Error communicating with server com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
09-10 08:14:13.491     795-1194/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://plus.google.com/... flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity} from uid 10011 on display 0
09-10 08:14:13.543  23045-23098/? W/BaseAppContext﹕ Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
09-10 08:14:13.590    1731-1731/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator﹕ onFinishInput()
09-10 08:14:13.609      795-813/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity: +80ms
```

More logs:

```
09-10 08:35:58.327    2148-2728/? E/MDM﹕ [145] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
09-10 08:35:58.332  19279-22527/? D/LocationInitializer﹕ Restart initialization of location
09-10 08:35:58.335  22495-22495/? I/GAv4-SVC﹕ Google Analytics 7.9.53 is starting up.
09-10 08:35:58.338     795-1268/? I/AccountManagerService﹕ getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
09-10 08:35:58.355  22495-22526/? D/NativeLibraryUtils﹕ Install completed successfully.
09-10 08:35:58.384  22495-22534/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-10 08:35:58.447  22495-22533/? W/BaseAppContext﹕ Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
09-10 08:35:58.460  22495-22533/? I/GLSUser﹕ [ChannelManager] Attempting to channel bind connection HttpClient.
09-10 08:35:58.467  22495-22534/? I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 08/12/15, 70b1c55, I9e0bc0c0ce
09-10 08:35:58.479  22495-22533/? I/GLSUser﹕ [ChannelManager] Checking whether channelId is enabled. isEnabledGmsCore? false, isEnabledSdk? true, isAtLeastKitKat? true
09-10 08:35:58.484  22495-22534/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-10 08:35:58.521    1731-1731/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator﹕ onFinishInput()
09-10 08:35:58.539      795-813/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.google.android.gms/.appinvite.AppInviteAcceptInvitationActivity: +368ms (total +399ms)
09-10 08:35:58.597  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.Exception: Error converting session
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.a.log(SourceFile:302)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.a.toSession(SourceFile:268)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ClientSessionContext.getSession(SourceFile:87)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.getCachedClientSession(SourceFile:709)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.getSessionToReuse(SourceFile:376)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SourceFile:294)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.a(SourceFile:258)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SourceFile:558)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:89)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:933)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:775)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:676)
09-10 08:35:58.599  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:660)
09-10 08:35:58.600  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(SourceFile:87)
09-10 08:35:58.600  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.d.performRequest(SourceFile:43)
09-10 08:35:58.600  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(SourceFile:96)
09-10 08:35:58.600  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.server.v.performRequest(SourceFile:48)
09-10 08:35:58.600  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(SourceFile:112)
09-10 08:35:58.600  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid session data
09-10 08:35:58.603  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSessionImpl.<init>(SourceFile:88)
09-10 08:35:58.603  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.a.toSession(SourceFile:267)
09-10 08:35:58.603  22495-22537/? W/System.err﹕ ... 27 more
```

Moreover - after a couple of hours it will start working for some time. Then it will stop.

Config details:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'
}
//...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.8.0'

//...
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Comment: fyi for everyone else: this discussion has been filed as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/65)

Answer (score 0):

You should verify the link you used to do teh AppInvite